# How to set width of a inline element?

Tags: css

I want to design a tab header. The html code is,

```
<div class="tab-header">
    <a href="" class="current">tab1-title</a>
    <a href="">tab2-title</a>
</div>
```

Now I need to apply a background image to the current class, too make effect like this,
[image]

But the inline element a is not big enough for this background image, so I adjust the width and height of the element a. But the adjustment failed, the width/height of the element did not change.

How could I get the right effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To apply width, set css property 'display' to either 'block' or 'inline-block'.

block: the element will sit in a single line. In such case you may want to set float so links are in the same line;

inline-block; the element will have height, width, etc, and multiple elements will sit in the same line (block).

Answer (score 4):

Set the [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) property to `inline-block`, and then you can set the `width`, `height`, and `vertical-align` as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the inline element.  With a little tweaking, this has wide cross-browser support and is incredibly useful for the kind of layout you're after.

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to use `display:block` on the anchor.

Comment: it's an inline element, why you want to convert it to block