# Width is not working

Tags: html, css

Sorry for this silly question, but i stick because of this problem, the width of the anchor tag is not working, basically i want to increase the height of the anchor tag so the text written in it does not wrap

```css
.filteredRestBody {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border: 1px dotted #5bc0de;
    border-top-left-radius: 23px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 grey;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: -14%;
    padding: 0 0 47px 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    width: 115%;
}

.filterThumbnails {
    background-position: 2px -19px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top-left-radius: 10%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 4.3%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 234px;
}

.restaurantThumbnailsTitle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    height: 95px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 44.7%;
    width: 114%;
}


.restaurantThumbnailsTitle > a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.restaurantThumbnailsTitleText {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: unset;
    left: 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 red;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="filteredRestBody" class="row filteredRestBody">
   <div id="row1" class="row">
       <div id="indianchilly" class="col-sm-4 filterThumbnails" style="background:url('images/yochinathumbbck.jpg')">
           <img src="images/bestoffers.png">
           <div id="discountNum">Discount 15%</div>
           <div class="ratingsContainer">
               <div id="restaurantThumbnailsTitle" class="restaurantThumbnailsTitle">
                   <a href="viewRestaurant.php?rest=yochina">Indian Chilly</a>
                   <p class="restaurantThumbnailsTitleText">chilled out chinese</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many things but only solution which i got by increasing the width of filterThumbnails which i do not want to increase, Please, anyone help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set width of a inline element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137772/how-to-set-width-of-a-inline-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an a tag is inline so it's not affected by width or height, add `display:inline-block;` to it's css and you should then be able to adjust it.

Comment: glad to have helped, don't forget to mark answered.

Answer (score 2):

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property):

> '**width**'
>
> - Value:   <length> | <percentage> | auto | inherit
> - Initial:     auto
> - Applies to:      all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups
> - Inherited:   no
> - Percentages:     refer to width of containing block
> - Media:   visual
> - Computed value:      the percentage or 'auto' as specified or the absolute length

`a` elements are, by default, non-replaced inline elements. So `width` property doesn't apply.

Comment: Exactly Oriol, i was just out of the clue, and it didn't came on my mind at all, Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements can't have altered width. You need to make that anchor a block, or inline-block, see here (gave it a green background so you can see how wide it is):

```css
.filteredRestBody {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border: 1px dotted #5bc0de;
    border-top-left-radius: 23px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 grey;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 0 47px 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    width: 115%;
}

.filterThumbnails {
    background-position: 2px -19px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-top-left-radius: 10%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 4.3%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 234px;
}

.restaurantThumbnailsTitle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    height: 95px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 44.7%;
    width: 114%;
  }

.restaurantThumbnailsTitle a {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
}

.restaurantThumbnailsTitle a:hover { 
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="filteredRestBody" class="row filteredRestBody">
   <div id="row1" class="row">
       <div id="indianchilly" class="col-sm-4 filterThumbnails" style="background:url('images/yochinathumbbck.jpg')">
           <img src="images/bestoffers.png">
           <div id="discountNum">Discount 15%</div>
           <div class="ratingsContainer">
               <div id="restaurantThumbnailsTitle" class="restaurantThumbnailsTitle">
                   <a href="viewRestaurant.php?rest=yochina">Indian Chilly</a>
                   <p class="restaurantThumbnailsTitleText">chilled out chinese</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```