# CSS box around text, set box size

Tags: html, css

I want to create a boxed border around some text, specifically numbers. But I want the box to be the same size, no matter if its a single digit number or a triple digit number. I've tried a couple things, but every time the border just wraps the number. The number will be wrap with the `<strong>` tag.

```css
strong{    
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Then why not place your text in a div with a fixed width and height styled with a border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a fixed `width` to that element

```css
strong {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcpvgykr/

Comment: This will not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137772/how-to-set-width-of-a-inline-element You need to change display property, too.

Comment: thanks @nevermind. i forgot to add that. i must have been excited, this was my first post :)

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, wrap your text using a `div` of fixed width and style the div with a border. Here is a live example:

```css
#theDiv {
  width: 300px;
  border: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">
  Your Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `<div>` tag in this situation (remember that you can place a div inside of div!) as it would look neat and you could do it pretty neatly. However it is also possible to make such a thing with '`padding:x`' on CSS style sheet, but I do not suggest this way as it would be less efficient than div.
When you write your divs surrounding those numbers, define a class for all of them. Let's say `<div class="numberBoxes"></div>` (between would be that number), then go to CSS stylesheet and write `.numberBoxes { }` inside of curly braces design that border (remember to put width and height of div! It won't show up, if you don't!)